# AWS code deploy Deployment Failed

Tags: github, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I am having a elastic load balancer with 2 instances running on it. I wanted to deploy an application to this elastic scaling group. I heard about was codedeply and trying. I am having few question regarding this. When i create a new deployment i am always getting Reconnect to GitHub. I can not solve this. Second when i am trying to deploy i got this error "Deployment could not continue: Constraint 'default' requires a minimum of 1 healthy hosts to continue. Remaining hosts are skipped. ".
So i check my elastic load balance and i found that i have a configuration of 2 desired instances and 2 minimum healthy instances. So i tried to modify that minimum healthy instances to 1 and it automatically terminate one instance. I don't know where i am doing mistake. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I couldn't solve this issue, may be some script issue., So i tried elastik beanstalk and it works as i expected. And it is very simple to configure too

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have existing healthy hosts. If not then temporarily change the deployment Configuration Type to *AllAtOnce* as this does not require healthy hosts prior to deployment. Once deployment is complete you can change it back to its original setting.

Also check the Auto Scaling Group target in the CodeDeploy Application Configuration is valid. A Blue-Green deployment will copy and replace the Auto Scaling Group so ensure the Application Configuration is using a valid source Auto Scaling Group to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, if you try to deploy from your Github repo, before you start your deployment you need to complete authentication process with Github.

For the second issue, you specify the instances you want to deploy to by adding tags in your deployment group. Make sure your instances are tagged correctly so CodeDeploy can find the instances during the deployment.

Comment: Facing same problem @ponraj

Answer (score 0):

I think you use CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime
(MinimumHealthyHosts:99%)

100Instances are running, you can success.

How about using
CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce(MinimumHealthyHosts:0%)
or 
CodeDeployDefault.HalfAtATime(MinimumHealthyHosts:50%)

I succeeded both AllAtOnce and HalfAtATime.
※using auto scaling group, and 1instance at AZ1a and 1instance at AZ1c.

Answer (score 0):

This thing got headache for me too. This is the way I fixed it.
This happens because the codeDeploy checks health of the ec2 instances by hitting instances by default on port 80. Before deployment, you need to run below bash script on the instances and check if the script worked. httpd service must be started. Reboot the instance.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo su
    yum update -y
    yum install httpd -y
    yum install ruby
    yum install aws-cli
    cd ~
    aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install . --region us-east-1
    chmod +x ./install
    ./install
    echo 'hello world' > /var/www/html/index.html
    hostname >> /var/www/html/index.html
    chkconfig httpd on
    service httpd start
```